# Why do cat5 cables sometimes have the fluffy fiber bit in them?

Tags: cable, cat5

Why do cat5 cables sometimes have the fluffy fiber bit in them?

Comment: Hi. I understand that you're new here, which is awesome :-) We're always glad to have new people. Just so you know, the more people that see a question, the more people that can answer (and vote up) the right one. As you found out, sometimes answers either aren't right, or aren't right completely. It's therefore in your best interest to leave a question open for a day or two, just to make sure you get enough feedback.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Actually it's for pulling the outer shielding away from the inner wires. When you're punching down the cable you pull the fiber string down from the top of the cable and it makes a nice split in the outer shielding that allows you to pull the outer shielding down to cut it off without damaging the inner wires. Here's a video that shows the process:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHy8mtW9eak at 1:23

Comment: +1, but I believe that it's also used to provide strength when making runs, so the pulling stress isn't entirely borne by the wires and sheathing.

Comment: It's not, it's strictly intended as a ripcord. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: @Matt there was some brand (ages ago) that had an embedded nylon fibers in the sheathing for "stress relief".  I don't think it ever sold well and I've never seen it since

Comment: What about that plastic cross section? Isn't that in some older or first generation to reduce cross talk? I think when CAT6 first came out I noticed it. It's a real pain.

Comment: Amusing. I find that to be pretty insane though.: that piece of junk string would be really hard to use that way.

Comment: It's surprisingly easy. I was mildly surprised the first time I tried it, but it works like a charm. Give it a try.

Comment: should point out you get these fibres on many cables, not just cat5.

Comment: I heard that the fiber was for wicking out any moisture, should it find its way into the cable.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Joe's answer; It adds *some* strength to the cable for pulling and *helps* prevent damage to the copper wires. For example, when you are pulling long runs.